# Find external resource inside jar

Tags: java, java-8, embedded-resource

I'm running my App and I'm using a jar as DSL program, which contains a functionality to create a File from a resource out of this Jar execution.

```
MyDSL.jar

  --File findFile(String path)

MyApp

  -- main/src/MyDSL.findFile(myResource.xml)
  -- main/resources/myResource.xml
```

Maybe that silly but even passing the absolute path to the jar method findFile I'm not able to find the resource.

What I¡m doing wrong here?.

Here my code:

The App

```
  String applicationContext = dir.concat("/src/main/resources/")
  String  resourceLocations = dir.concat("/src/test/resources/config/")

ActorTestDSL()
        .withApplicationConf(applicationContext + "application.conf")
        .withAkkaContext(resourceLocations + "akkaContext.xml")
        .build()
```

And in the Jar DSL

```
val resourceLocations = Array[String](akkaContextPath)
context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(resourceLocations: _*)
```

context always fail since it cannot find the akkaContext.xml

Regards.

Comment: Could you share the findFile code?

Comment: Hi I already did

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `"/src/main/resources/"`… so you expect your source folders to be included in the deployed executable jar file?